# Icon menu in application

Tags: android, text, menu, icons, fill

I would like to show a menu with icons with text below every icon in Android.

The menu should fill the entire activity, like the launcher menu. For example:

[image]

I want the user to choose from a set of options (static options) with icons.

I was thinking about a grid view with buttons or images, but how to get the text in without burning them into the icons (translation later on)?

Comment: The answer to this question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982386/android-simple-gridview-that-displays-text-in-the-grids

Comment: That kind of menu is called a Sliding Drawer - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html