# How to add text to an empty GridLayout in Android?

Tags: android, grid-layout

TextView has setText(String), but when looking on the Doc, I don't see one for GridLayout. Is there an adapter or something that I need to use instead? If so, which one? Thanks in advance for any of the help.

Comment: yes, you need an adapter

Comment: I just added it to clarify I want more than just a single word response lol.

Comment: you can create an adapter which extends `BaseAdapter`, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982386/android-simple-gridview-that-displays-text-in-the-grids) is an example.

Comment: What I was thinking about using was a GridLayout, but the tutorial is GridView. My question is for a calendar layout, which one makes sense? And you might want to put what you told me in an answer.

Comment: sorry, my mistake... well then you can't use an adapter for `GridLayout`, since it is a `ViewGroup`, you can only add views to it. I think a `GridView` should do for a calendar.

Comment: Oh no, thats fine. You definitely gave me a great starting point. I really appreciate it. But I will definitely look into GridView.

Comment: There is one thing I am confused about. What exactly is a context

Comment: i've got this question when i started programming Android, hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android) can help you. as a practice, i usually create a member variable `private Context mContext = this;`, and whenever i need Context, i'll put `mContext` to it.

Comment: Btw, you should probably put your answer so I can accept it lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridLayout` is a `ViewGroup`, to which you can only add views; if you want to make a calendar, it would be better to use a `GridView`.

for the `GridView`, create an adapter which extends `BaseAdapter`, and use `TextView` for the grid's layout. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982386/android-simple-gridview-that-displays-text-in-the-grids) is an example.