# How do I display dynamically generated strings with a gridview in android?

Tags: android, string, gridview, dynamic

I have an array of numbers, and I would like to display them from the most recently added, in the following format: The array index folowed by a colon, the number and depending on which number it is, also an exclaimation like this:

`10:35, 09:41!, 08:17, 07:5!...`

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Simple GridView that displays text in the grids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982386/android-simple-gridview-that-displays-text-in-the-grids)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly like a ListView...

The Hello Gridview example in the SDK is what you need:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Just replace ImageAdapter by a TextAdapter and that's it!

public class TextAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

```
public TextAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new TextView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        textView = new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        textView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        textView = (TextView) convertView;
    }

    textView.setText(strings[position]);
    return textView;
}

// references to our texts
private String[] strings = {
        "10:35","09:41!","08:17","07:5!",...
};
```

}

Comment: Thanks I have it working. However, the code that generates the string data is in the main activity, and the gridview is in a second activity which is started by the first. So I have instantiated a _static_ TextAdapter in the MainActivity so I can access it from both activities. I then update the adapter's _private_ strings array with _public_ addString() and remString() methods which I have created within it. Is a static object the best way to do this, and is it best to have in the first or second activity?