# Text View is not shown in Grid View with images

Tags: android, image, gridview, textview

[image]
I am making app with Grid View for android. I got this code for Grid View with text view under images. But text view is not shown. Eclipse is not showing me any errors or anything in logcat

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    TextView text;
    private String[] mThumbTxt = {
            "Example Text 1", "Example Text 2", "Example Text 3", " Example Text 4","Example Text 5",
            "Example Text 1", "Example Text 2", "Example Text 3", " Example Text 4","Example Text 5",
            "Example Text 1", "Example Text 2", "Example Text 3", " Example Text 4","Example Text 5",
            "Example Text 1", "Example Text 2", "Example Text 3", " Example Text 4","Example Text 5",
            "Example Text 1", "Example Text 2", "Example Text 3", " Example Text 4","Example Text 5",
            "Example Text 1", "Example Text 2", "Example Text 3", " Example Text 4","Example Text 5",
            " Example Text 4","Example  5",


    };


// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,
        R.drawable.img3,  R.drawable.img4, 
        R.drawable.img5,  R.drawable.img6, 
        R.drawable.img7,  R.drawable.img20, 
        R.drawable.img8,  R.drawable.img21, 
        R.drawable.img9,  R.drawable.img22, 
        R.drawable.img10,  R.drawable.img23, 
        R.drawable.img11,  R.drawable.img24, 
        R.drawable.img12,  R.drawable.img25, 
        R.drawable.img13,  R.drawable.img26, 
        R.drawable.img14,  R.drawable.img27, 
        R.drawable.img15,  R.drawable.img28, 
        R.drawable.img16,  R.drawable.img29, 
        R.drawable.img17,  R.drawable.img30, 
        R.drawable.img18,  R.drawable.img31, 
        R.drawable.img19
};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    text=new TextView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(270, 270));
    text.setText(mThumbTxt[position]);  
    return imageView;
}
```

What is wrong with this code? What I did wrong? 
Separate XML layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982386/android-simple-gridview-that-displays-text-in-the-grids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView` is not showing because you have only returned the `ImageView` as a view in your `getView()` method.

You need to create separate layout for that you will have to return the layout which will contain the `ImageView` and `TextView`.

**OR**

You can create a `LinearLayout` dynamically in which you add your `ImageView` and `TextView` and return your `LinearLayout`

```
  return layout;
```

Try out as below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     LinearLayout linearlayout=new LinearLayout(mContext);
     ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
     text=new TextView(mContext);
     linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(270, 270));
    text.setText(mThumbTxt[position]); 

      linearlayout.addView(imageView);
      linearlayout.addView(text);
    return linearlayout;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that is working, text View is shown now but it's on right side of image, how can I make it to be under image?

Comment: @user3094736 use `RelativeLayout`. or set orientation to vertical

Comment: Make `linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`. @user3094736

Comment: Oh yea now it's working perfectly. Thanks! Thank you both to bad I can't chose 2 answers

Answer (score 1):

In `getview` you have

```
return imageView;
```

So its normal only imageview is displayed. Wrap `ImageView` and `TextView`in a `RelativeLayout/LinearLayout` and return the view.

OR inflate a layout with imageView and textView and return the view.

Edit:

In the constructor

```
   LayoutInflater mInflater; 
   public ImageAdapter(Context c){
       mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
   }
```

Then in `getView`

```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder;
  if (convertView == null) { 
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, 
                         parent, false);
      holder = new ViewHolder(); 
      holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
      holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      convertView.setTag(holder); 
       } else { 
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
       } 
           holder.iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
           holder.tv.setText(mThumbTxt[position]);
     return convertView;
 }
```

Then

```
static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView tv;
    ImageView iv;
}
```

Reference:

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

[How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

Comment: @user3094736 then there is no need to create a layout programaticalle

Comment: Um the user @GrlsHu has made it working, but it's shown on right side of image instead below.

Comment: @user3094736 try the edit its more efficient. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: @user3094736 you need to set the linerlayout orientation to vertical. By default its horizontal. By the way if you inflate the layout you posted it should coz its has orientation vertical `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

Take a

```
ViewHolder holder; 
   holder = new ViewHolder();
```

and and this image and text in this ViewHolder object wd help of LayoutInflater and return  convertView as paramerter of your getview 
here u only return image view dude

After looking around some more, I found a great example of exactly how to do this here:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-grid-view-example-with-image-and-text.html

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Add the content of the link in your answer or post links as comments